# Group items in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, group-by, query-optimization

The below stored procedure counts the number of calls and talk time grouped by hours, in a particular day, from a calls stats table.

It has the following output:

[image]

However I still need to group these results by another two fields (number types, beginning with 00, 01/02, 084 etc): `innumber` and `outnumber`. So the desired output example should be:

[image]

Here's the stored procedure:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetHourStats`(IN _ID INT, IN _CALLTYPE INT, IN _YEAR INT, IN _MONTH INT, IN _DAY INT)
    BEGIN

    set @_START = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date(_YEAR * 10000 + _MONTH * 100 + _DAY * 1)); 
set @_END = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_add(date(_YEAR * 10000 + _MONTH * 100 + _DAY * 1), interval 1 day));

SELECT *, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT 
        `cdrs`.`stype` AS `stype`,
        `cdrs`.`dtype` AS `dtype`,
        `cdrs`.`uniqueid` AS `UniqueID`,
        `cdrs`.`dcustomer` AS `dcustomer`,
        `cdrs`.`callid` AS `callid`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`snumber` = _LATIN1'') THEN 'Anonymous'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`snumber` IS NOT NULL) THEN `cdrs`.`snumber`
        END) AS `called`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external') THEN 2
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external') THEN 3
        END) AS `calltype`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "01%" OR `cdrs`.`snumber` like "02%") THEN '01-02'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "080%") THEN '080'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "084%") THEN '084'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "087%") THEN '087'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "07%") THEN '07'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "09%") THEN '09'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "00%") THEN '00'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "04%") THEN '04'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "03%") THEN '03'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "02%") THEN '02'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "05%") THEN '05'
        END) AS `innumber`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "01%" OR `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "02%") THEN '01-02'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "080%") THEN '080'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "084%") THEN '084'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "087%") THEN '087'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "07%") THEN '07'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "09%") THEN '09'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "00%") THEN '00'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "04%") THEN '04'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "03%") THEN '03'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "02%") THEN '02'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "05%") THEN '05'
        END) AS `outnumber`,
        `cdrs`.`sname` AS `description`,
        `cdrs`.`cnumber` AS `calling`,
        `cdrs`.`cnumber` AS `DTN`,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(`cdrs`.`start`) AS `start`,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(`cdrs`.`end`) AS `end`,
        FROM_UNIXTIME((`cdrs`.`end` - `cdrs`.`talktime`)) AS `answered`,
        (`cdrs`.`end` - `cdrs`.`start`) AS `duration`,
        `cdrs`.`talktime` AS `talktime`,
        ((`cdrs`.`end` - `cdrs`.`start`) - `cdrs`.`talktime`) AS `TTA`,
        `cdrs`.`status` AS `status`
    FROM `cdrs`
    WHERE `cdrs`.`start` >= @_START and `cdrs`.`start` < @_END
    ) cdr1 
  WHERE (_CALLTYPE = 1 OR cdr1.calltype = _CALLTYPE)
  GROUP BY cdr1.`callid`) cdr

    JOIN customers ON id = cdr.dcustomer 
    WHERE (parent = _ID or cdr.dcustomer = _ID or parent IN 
        (SELECT id FROM customers WHERE parent = _ID)) 
    AND HOUR(start) = h.idhour
) as 'count',

(
    SELECT sum(talktime) 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT 
        `cdrs`.`stype` AS `stype`,
        `cdrs`.`dtype` AS `dtype`,
        `cdrs`.`uniqueid` AS `UniqueID`,
        `cdrs`.`dcustomer` AS `dcustomer`,
        `cdrs`.`callid` AS `callid`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`snumber` = _LATIN1'') THEN 'Anonymous'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`snumber` IS NOT NULL) THEN `cdrs`.`snumber`
        END) AS `called`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external') THEN 2
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external') THEN 3
        END) AS `calltype`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "01%" OR `cdrs`.`snumber` like "02%") THEN '01-02'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "080%") THEN '080'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "084%") THEN '084'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "087%") THEN '087'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "07%") THEN '07'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "09%") THEN '09'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "00%") THEN '00'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "04%") THEN '04'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "03%") THEN '03'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "02%") THEN '02'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`stype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`snumber` like "05%") THEN '05'
        END) AS `innumber`,
        (CASE
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "01%" OR `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "02%") THEN '01-02'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "080%") THEN '080'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "084%") THEN '084'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "087%") THEN '087'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "07%") THEN '07'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "09%") THEN '09'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "00%") THEN '00'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "04%") THEN '04'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "03%") THEN '03'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "02%") THEN '02'
            WHEN (`cdrs`.`dtype` = _LATIN1'external' AND `cdrs`.`dnumber` like "05%") THEN '05'
        END) AS `outnumber`,
        `cdrs`.`sname` AS `description`,
        `cdrs`.`cnumber` AS `calling`,
        `cdrs`.`cnumber` AS `DTN`,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(`cdrs`.`start`) AS `start`,
        FROM_UNIXTIME(`cdrs`.`end`) AS `end`,
        FROM_UNIXTIME((`cdrs`.`end` - `cdrs`.`talktime`)) AS `answered`,
        (`cdrs`.`end` - `cdrs`.`start`) AS `duration`,
        `cdrs`.`talktime` AS `talktime`,
        ((`cdrs`.`end` - `cdrs`.`start`) - `cdrs`.`talktime`) AS `TTA`,
        `cdrs`.`status` AS `status`
    FROM `cdrs`
    WHERE `cdrs`.`start` >= @_START and `cdrs`.`start` < @_END
    ) cdr1 
  WHERE (_CALLTYPE = 1 OR cdr1.calltype = _CALLTYPE)
  GROUP BY cdr1.`callid`) cdr

    JOIN customers ON id = cdr.dcustomer 
    WHERE (parent = _ID or cdr.dcustomer = _ID or parent IN 
        (SELECT id FROM customers WHERE parent = _ID))

    AND HOUR(start) = h.idhour
) as 'duration'

    FROM hub.hours h ORDER BY idhour;

END
```

**Q:** How can I achieve the desired output? Can this stored procedure be simplified / optimized ?

Comment: If I were trying to work on this query, I'd do two things: (1) build a lookup table to get rid of the vast CASE statements, (2) do it in straight SQL, get it working, and then put it into a stored procedure.

Comment: can you give me some examples or links on how to get rid of the CASE statements ?

Comment: A huge chunk of that code looks "common".  If it is identical, consider creating a temporary table, inserting the stuff into it, adding an index (or two) to the temp table, then constructing the final `SELECT` from it.  (Caution: the temporary table from `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` cannot be referenced more than once, so you may need another trick.)